# adding string at the end of the file python

Tags: python

Clarification:
So if my file has 10 lines:
THe first line is a heading, so I want to append some text at the end of first line

THen I have a list which contains 9 elements..

I want to read that list and append the end of each line with corresponding element..

So basically list[0] to second line, list[1] to third line and so on..

---

I have a file which is delimted by comma.
something like this:

```
A,B,C
0.123,222,942
......
```

Now I want to do something like this:

```
A,B,C,D #append "D" just once
0.123,222,942,99293
............
```

This "D" is actually saved in a list so yeah I have this "D"
How do I do this? I mean I know the naive way.
like go thru each line and do something like

```
string += str(list[i])
```

Basically how do i append something at the end of the file in pythonic way :)

Comment: Please clarify what you been by 'at the end of the file' - normally I'd presume you meant literally right at the end, but your example seems to show appending things to the end of a specific line in the file - which is a very different problem. Also, post the code you have already tried.

Comment: so you don't want to append it to the _end_ of the file, you want to find that string _in_ the file and append a "D" (or whatever string you want)?

Comment: Hi, basically end of each line.
SO if i have 20 lines in a file, I will have a list of len 19 . first line is the heading and for the rest of 19, i want to read from that list and append the corresponding line with corresponding element in the list

Comment: Where does `99293` come from?

Comment: oh, consider rewriting your question / title to reflect that, it's not very clear

Comment: @Shep: sorry I rewrote the clarification is it making any sense now?

Comment: @Fraz alright but the `942` dissapears when you said you were appending to each line.

Comment: @jamylak: my bad.. i fixed that

Comment: You will need to copy the entire file, line by line, and add whatever you need to lines of your choice as you go along. There's no stable way of adding things to the end of a line in a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a new file:

```
data = ['header', 1, 2, 3, 4]

with open("infile", 'r') as inf, open("infile.2", 'w') as outf:
    outf.writelines('%s,%s\n' % (s.strip(), n) for s, n in zip(inf, data))
```

If you want to "update" the input file, just rename the new one afterwards

```
import os
os.unlink("infile")
os.rename("infile.2", "infile")
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Use [the `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html?highlight=dic#module-contents).

Long answer:

```
import csv

newvalues = [...]

with open("path/to/input.csv") as file:
    data = list(csv.reader(file))

with open("path/to/input.csv", "w") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row, newvalue in zip(data, newvalues):
        row.append(newvalue)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Naturally, this depends on the lines in the file and `newvalues` being the same length. If this isn't the case, you could use something like [`zip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to fill in the excess lines with a given value.

If you are doing this to the different files, we can do it even more easily:

```
import csv

newvalues = [...]

with open("path/to/input.csv") as from, open("path/to/output.csv", "w") as to:
    reader = csv.reader(from)
    writer = csv.writer(to)
    for row, newvalue in zip(reader, newvalues):
        row.append(newvalue)
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This also has the advantage of not reading the entire file into memory, so for very large files, this is a better solution.